# iPhone mobile safari JSON parse error

Tags: php, jquery, json, mobile, safari

I am using php json_encode to encode arrays of objects and storing them in a hidden div. Then using jquery.parseJSON to put them into js arrays of objects to work with. I am using jQuery v1.7. The exact error is JavaScript Error on Line 2: SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string. This error only occurs on the mobile version of safari. FF, Chrome, IE Safari and android all work, it only pulls this error with mobile safari. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please show the JSON you are trying to decode, as it appears in the browser where it fails. My guess is that it really does have a syntax error in it, but this only occurs in mobile safari for whatever reason.

Comment: {"data":[{"id":"464","url":"detailPage\/firstName-lastName","name":"firstName middleInitial. lastName","title":"professional title","location":"city, state","location_url":["location-detail\/city",null],"phone":"555-555-5555 ","email":"email@email.com"}]}

Answer (score 8):

After eliminating different fields, I discovered the problem was only in phone numbers. The automatic detection of phone numbers either interfered with json or json interfered with the detection of phone numbers. Adding `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` solved the error.

Comment: You are really great!